# XCode Swift AWS S3 Upload Not Working

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

For some reason the upload to S3 does work not whereas I was able to get the download function to work just fine.

Here is my upload code:

@IBAction func uploadFile(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    let CognitoRegionType = AWSRegionType.USWest2  // e.g. AWSRegionType.USEast1
    let CognitoIdentityPoolId = "us-west-2:3c00122a-866c-4ce4-9dd3-ee23c16e58f3"

    let DefaultServiceRegionType = AWSRegionType.USWest1 // e.g. AWSRegionType.USEast1
    let S3BucketName = "snappcastphotos"


    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:CognitoRegionType, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType , credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration


    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest?.key = "bingo"
    uploadRequest?.body = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/users/rhom/desktop/test.rtf")

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in

        if let error = task.error as? NSError {
            if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
                switch code {
                case .cancelled, .paused:
                    break
                default:
                    print("Error uploading: \(uploadRequest?.key) Error: \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error uploading: \(uploadRequest?.key) Error: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }

        let uploadOutput = task.result
        print("Upload complete for: \(uploadRequest?.key)")
        return nil
    })
}
```

and this code produces the following error/output:

Error uploading: Optional("bingo") Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={HostId=KAsbvIqiY67dr/64f3uvZPB1Lr5Vj7eNNV198DLai/RG/tA+v3To8CBbnbFSM00V2COZnzebx/M=, Message=The request body terminated unexpectedly, Code=IncompleteBody, RequestId=A95236E53A1B8FE8}

Anyone have any ideas?  I can't find any clue as to why the download works using Cognito and S3 but the upload doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

It looks more of an authorization error. Check if you are having the write permissions for this particular bucket and also check the path you are giving is correct, as if there is a mismatch it wont work.

Comment: yes I checked permissions in Cognito and S3 bucket to make sure they have read/write...  will keep on searching but thx for comment

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this problem out :)

It turns out that I had installed an older version of AWS Frameworks as I was following an older tutorial to get started... and had loaded the frameworks using Cocoapods specifying in the podfile for IOS 8.0 but I am IOS 10.0 now!!!!  so changing the podfile to version 10.0 fixed the problem.

I ended up reinstalling AWS Frameworks using Cocoapods and the correct podfile with 10.0... but I think there is a way to just update the pod but I will look into that later

Hope this helps anyone who has this problem too :)